# Local dependency with git commit

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

In my stack.yaml file, I want to add a dependency to a package located on my computer.

I can do it like this:

```
- location : ../Bwroga
  extra-dep: true
```

Is it possible to also specify a commit? I know I can do this if the package is hosted on github or bitbucket, but I want to keep the dependency on my computer.

I tried:

```
- location :
    git: ../Bwroga
    commit: 039bd43313803a88c990af3ddcd6d75419ab44a1
  extra-dep: true

- location :
    git: ../Bwroga/bwroga.git
    commit: 039bd43313803a88c990af3ddcd6d75419ab44a1
  extra-dep: true
```

but got errors stating that the repository does not exist.

I also tried:

```
- location: ../Bwroga
  commit: 039bd43313803a88c990af3ddcd6d75419ab44a1
  extra-dep: true
```

It compiled, but said that the commit field was unrecognized.

Comment: I expect `git` requires a bare repository, and not one with a working tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note: it would be a good idea to include the error messages you receive in the future.

I just checked this myself, and I can see why it doesn't work. When cloning the target repo, Stack will change into a new temporary directory first. Then, the relative path in the `stack.yaml` file is no longer valid. If you want, you can work around this using an absolute path in the `stack.yaml` file.

In theory we could add support to Stack to detect that a relative path to a repo has been given and convert it into an absolute path. But I think the use case would need to be worked out more fully to justify such a change. I believe most commonly the approach you're describing is handled via Git submodules.

Comment: "When cloning the target repo, Stack will change into a new temporary directory first" - Why? `git-clone` supports being told what directory to clone into.

Comment: That should be possible, and not particularly difficult to change, if you're interested in sending a PR.

Comment: Thanks. I'm fine with absolute paths.

Comment: That's awesome!

Comment: @amalloy Thanks!